Does the Prometheus's tomcat_servlet_request_seconds measure the time taken to wait in the Tomcat queue?
To my understanding, Prometheus's tomcat_servlet_request_seconds metric measures the time taken for the dispatcher servlet to handle the request after the request has reached it, which does not include the time taken to pass through filters etc.
Would it be correct to also say that hence, it does not include the time taken to wait in the Tomcat queue? Since the request would only be passed down to the dispatcher servlet once a thread has actually been assigned to the request, and the flow after (before the request reaches the servlet) has been completed.
This happened because we had a metric for Tomcat's queue size, that spiked at the same time with the processing time from tomcat_servlet_request_seconds.
